# Is this section also about how to formulate good explanations?

Tags: support

Can you look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655534/how-this-js-jquery-syntax-work

I tried to show every point which was not clear. Most of time I read a university book they were completely unclear. The teacher were giving everything as understood.

But this is my personal idea. I would like to ask if there are resources, tools, website or anything else for improving the quality of slides, books or eLearning in the direction I've showed in the question on StackOverflow.

Can I open such a question here?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but what is the question you are proposing to ask?

Comment: When people write books they give many stuff as understood. This, in my opinion, is the reason why Math (for example) is hard. I remember when I read symbols wondering what they were. The question I've linked clarifies everything. I wonder if this intuition that I've wrote now has been lead on by someone else. If someone has made a scale to measure symbols given as understood on a book of math for example.